# Access /data/data per Symlink

Tags: adb, sync

I have the following question:

I have an App on my mobile phone and on my tablet, and I would like to synchronize the data. Unfortunately the App can not do it. I know, the App stores all the important data in the /data/data sqlite Database. So here is my idea:

Is it possible to symlink (or hardlink) (with adb terminal?) the sqlite Database into a directory, which I can access, and then I could use folderSync to sync that file, so I would have synced the appData. Is Something like this possible? This is the only possibility to sync it, without root.

Answer (score 3):

No, that wouldn't remove the requirement for root. Symlinks don't get around the permission system in that way. If you try to access a file via a symlink, you still need to have permission to access the target of the link. Hardlinks don't check permissions when you access the file, but they do when you create the link, so you would still need root.

This would be a bit of a security vulnerability if it worked that way, not just on Android, but on Linux desktops and servers too.

Apart from that, it's a bit of a flaky way to sync data. If you make a change on your phone while it's offline, and then make a change on the tablet before the sync happens, whichever one doesn't sync first will lose its change. You need to manage that very carefully, and it's very easy to get caught out by accident. If the app developer adds the feature, they can consider changes separately and work out a useful way to merge them.